# Improved thumbnail extraction from videos

Tags: video, opencv, ffmpeg, thumbnails, video-processing

I have been using FFmpeg to find the middle frame of a h264 video file, and extract the jpg thumbnail for use on a streaming portal. This is done automatically for each uploaded video.

Sometimes the frame happens to be a black frame or just semantically bad i.e. a background or blurry shot which doesn't relate well to the video content.

I wonder if I can use openCV or some other method/library to programmatically find better thumbnails through facial recognition or frame analysis.

Answer (score 11):

I've run into that problem myself and came up with a very crude-yet-simple algorithm to ensure my thumbnails were more *"interesting*".  How?

1. Create *x*-number of thumbnails all at different points.  E.g. 5 thumbnails
2. Use the largest (in bytes) file and discard the rest

Why does this work?  Because jpeg files of a monotone 'boring' image, like an all black screen, compress into a much smaller files than an image with many objects and colors in it.

It's not perfect, but is a viable **[80/20](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle)** solution.  (Solves 80% of the problem with 20% of the work.)  Coding something that actually analyzes the image itself is going to be considerably more work.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds crude but solves the black frames issue with little effort.

Answer (score 2):

Libavfilter has got a thumbnail filter, which is meant to pick the most representative frame from a series of frames. Not sure how it works, but heres the docs http://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html#thumbnail

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs a two liner (using ffmpeg and imagemagick):

(this picks a max of 20 frames from the video and uses gt(scene) to pick transition moments. It uses ffmpeg to make 120pixel wide pngs and then imagemagick to make a gif (because the ffmpeg gifs are notoriously ugly...) It *might* fail if nothing happens in the movie, but then you shouldn't call it a movie - should you?

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -loglevel error -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.1), scale=120:-1" -frames:v 20 -f image2 -vsync 0 -an ./tmp/img%05d.png 
convert -delay 25 -loop 0 ./tmp/img*.png thumb.gif
```